# p5: resize canvas, with a fixed starting width/height?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm playing around with using p5 and tensorflow. I created a "face-filter", that tracks the nose and ears with tensorflow, and append images to those locations. For instance if my face-filter is "clown', the nose will have a red nose, and the ears will have clown ears.

Everything works, but now I'm trying trying to make the canvas responsive.

My canvas dimensions are `createCanvas(1200, 768)`, and it's centered in css.

How can I make the canvas responsive based on browser width? I'm just not sure how to setup the code in the `windowResized` function.

```
function windowResized(){
  resizeCanvas(width?, height?);
}
```

Appreciate any input I could get.

Answer (score 1):

p5.js provides the system variables [`windowWidth`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/windowWidth) and [`windowHeight`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/windowHeight), [`width`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/width) and [`height`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/height). While `width` and `height` store the current size of the canvas, `windowWidth` and `windowHeight` stores the width of the inner window.
Use `windowWidth` and `windowHeight`  in [`windowResized()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/windowResized) to resize the canvas:

```js
function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

The variables can also be used, when the canvas is created:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```